# In Android, how to get default focus on Back/Home button on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a Fragment extending from PreferenceFragment, how to get the default focus on the Back/Home button in the ActionBar.

At present the default focus is on the first entry in the list.

Tried the below code in the main activity as well, however it gave NULL Pointer Exception,

`View home = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
 home.requestFocus();`

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following? (It's more of a hack, the underlying assumption is that the home button is the first child)

```
private void requestBackButtonFocus() {
    if (toolbar != null) {
        int childrenCount = toolbar.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
            if (toolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageButton) {
                toolbar.getChildAt(i).requestFocus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```